# How to enumerate all cells in an Excel sheet with a (non-empty) value using openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I need to analyze the contents of Excel sheets (.xslx) programatically using `openpyxl`.

My problem is that some excel sheets have a very large number of empty rows, e.g. the `3. Access Control` worksheet below has 1048534 rows and 16384 columns, although only the first 100 rows are non-empty. This results in billions of cells, which is simply not feasible to enumerate over, e.g.:

```
for i in range(ws.max_row + 1):
   for j in range(ws.max_column + 1):
      value = ws.cell(i, j)
      ...
```

I want to avoid spilling information, e.g. skip a non-empty row exists at index 10000. Thus a solution to only analyze the first N rows simply doesn't work for my use case.

Does `openpyxl` support a way to filter all these superfluous rows, and only return a set of rows containing at least one non-empty cell?

```
>>> for ws in wb.worksheets:
...     print(ws.title, ws.max_row, ws.max_column)
...
0. Intro 16 7
1. Solution Profile 63 8
2. Solution Diagram 6 4
1.BE 18 29
3. Access Control 1048534 16384.    <-- PROBLEM
4. Systems Development 46 21
5. Operational Security 43 14
6. Data Communication 11 14
7. Other 27 16
3-7.BE 6 3
8. Risk Assessment 15 29
8.BE 20 16
9. Conclusions 36 8
EBA Risk Statement 51 13
Vulnerabilities 86 5
Threats 44 4
Sample IT Risks 167 6
9.BE 5 1
Risk matrix 19 11
9. Document change log 28 6
>>> (1048534 * 16384) / 1000000
17179.181056
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you're doing. You could load each sheet into a Pandas Dataframe which has methods for dealing with this. Otherwise the following should help:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    if not any(row):
       continue
```

Comment: thank you. But why would your approaches be faster than mine? In either case, Pandas or your code, every cell needs to be checked for a value, right? - or how is it possible for them to determine, e.g. "after row 10000 there are no more values"?

Comment: Mine works fine in read-only mode which is as fast as it gets but it will depend somewhat on the Dimensions element in the worksheet being useful. For full control you can look at the `_cells` dictionary of the worksheet and check the keys. NB cells may exist even if they are None.

Comment: Will you provide a full example, also setting read-only mode (or do you mean `values=only` is read-only mode)? In my case, where only the first 100 rows contain values, will your solution skip over the remaining rows (the total rows reported by `openpyxl` is 1048534 for the entire worksheet) when using `ws.iter_rows`? If not, then the code will loop 1048534 times (which happens in my tests), which is very slow, since `pyopenxl` presumably have to look at every cell in the row to create the object returned by each iteration?

Comment: Is there any limit on how many rows `openpyxl` will report the Excel sheet has? Could an Excel sheet have an arbitrary number of rows, like 100 billion rows?